# can't creating random groups in reasonable running time

Tags: performance, math, random

I have a personal project I'm working and I have an issue that I can't seem to solve (well, I can't solve it quickly).

Let's say I have a group of `x[1..|x|]` people, and a group of `x` elements.

I want to create x groups (group number `i` is for person number `i`) and in each group there are `y` different elements.

For example: if I have 10 people and 10 elements and I want each group will have 2 elements:

```
|   0   |1  |2  |3  |4  |5  |6  |7  |8  |9  |
|___________________________________________|
|   7   |4  |0  |6  |2  |8  |3  |1  |9  |5  |
|   6   |9  |5  |8  |7  |0  |2  |3  |1  |4  |
```

The top row represents the people `(0..9)`;
the two numbers below each person says which elements he have.
Notice: every element appears only two times (not more and not less).
Also notice that person number `i` can't have the element number `i`.
For example: person number 3 can't have element number 3.

My problem is how to create those groups (quickly).
The best solution I found so far is to create a matrix with `x` column and `y` rows;
take an array with size `x` , shuffle it, and then to see if I can't insert it to the matrix. If I can, move to the next row; if I can't shuffle it again and see if now it can be inserted.

The problem is, that even with small numbers (1000 people/elements and in each group 50 elements) the code is very slow.
The problem is with the shuffle, when it tries to find a match to row (~13) it needs to reshuffle many times until it finds a row it can place inside the matrix.

Does anyone know how this thing can be done quickly? Any ideas will be welcomed!!

Thx.

Comment: @beta , yes , a not random solution will be to do a shift and then I can find a solution very quickly.

I had a thought of selecting a group of prime numbers from the range 1..|x| ( randomly. selecting y prime numbers ) and then doing the shift with the prime numbers as the shift parameter. but I don't know how random the result will be.

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate though people, for each placing y elements of that number in random groups that are not full. just have an array with the vacant groups and remove them when they fill up, and of course exclude the current group from the random selection.

Comment: It is not obvious that this will result in a uniform random shuffle. Often you will find that shuffling techniques that seem uniform are actually biased, but it can be difficult to identify this except in testing. For example, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle.

Comment: That won't work.think of 5 people with 5 elements and you want that in each group there will be 2 elements .
pool of elements to place ( 0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4}
now I iterate over the pool, starting with 0:
group #0:
group #1:0
group #2:0
group #3:
group #4:
Now 1:
group #0:1
group #1:0
group #2:0 1
group #3:
group #4:

Now 2:
group #0:1 2
group #1:0 2
group #2:0 1
group #3:
group #4:

and now I'm left with {3,3,4,4}
and that I can't place in the remaining groups.

Comment: @Bitwise you are right this might be biased in some way, hard to check though... you can randomize the order of the groups insted of iterating them, but i'm afraid this doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In mathematical terms, what you want is to generate a random permutation without fixed points. This is called a this is called a derangement (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) for more details including the probability of a random permutation being a derangement). If you google "generate random derangement" or something similar you will find several implementations.

Comment: The problem is not to generate one permutation without fixed points, but I need to generate y permutations without fixed points.so if I have x people I need to create something like this: (∀x1,x2∈y & x1 != x2) => (∀i∈[1..|x|]=>x1[i]!=x2[i]) .

Comment: But if you can generate one derangement efficiently, why is it a problem to just do that many times?

Comment: @Bitwise problem is you are not allowed to have duplicates in any group i.e. no 2 derangements should place any given number in the same place.